# OkHttp client does not respect Accept header

Tags: java, json, okhttp

Making request with same url and different accept header returns previous response from okhttp cache.

This means that first request is made for application/json data, the second one requests application/xml. Client therefore returns json data from cache instead of doing xml upstream.

For example GET request: http://example.com with header application/json returns Cache-Control header and json payload. 
Response gets cached in internal http cache.
The second request is made within cache-control window to http://example.com with header application/xml. In this case Okhttp returns same json payload from cache rather than xml payload.

```java
Builder builder = new Builder().url("https://httpbin.org/headers").header("accept", header);
```

Did anyone experienced that problem already?

Comment: Maybe show us a short piece of code, and its output, demonstrating the problem?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/gpor89/c69c795b334af5ff63cef6468222a01e but test passes for this resource because the site does not return cache headers.

Comment: Not on Gist. Questions should be self-contained. You don't need the whole of the code, just enough that people can see what you're doing -- and show your output.

Answer (score 2):

The relevant RFC, describing how a cache should work is here: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.6 :

> If the selecting request header fields for the cached entry do not match the selecting request header fields of the new request, then the cache MUST NOT use a cached entry to satisfy the request unless it first relays the new request to the origin server in a conditional request and the server responds with 304 (Not Modified), including an entity tag or Content-Location that indicates the entity to be used.

The source code to OkHttp's `Cache` is here: https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/Cache.java

The cache key is just, the resource's URL. But the cache entry is compared against "vary" request headers too:

```
Response response = entry.response(snapshot);

if (!entry.matches(request, response)) {
  Util.closeQuietly(response.body());
  return null;
}
```

...

```
public boolean matches(Request request, Response response) {
  return url.equals(request.url().toString())
      && requestMethod.equals(request.method())
      && HttpHeaders.varyMatches(response, varyHeaders, request);
}
```

It's possibly you've found a bug, of course. I suggest bringing in the OkHttp source JAR, debugging with a breakpoint in the Cache.get() method, and stepping through to see if/when it goes wrong. If it does, raise with the maintainers or submit a patch.

Comment: The _key_ is just the URL, but it considers headers from the stored response and incoming request when deciding whether to return the cached response.

Comment: @JesseWilson Ah, looking closer, so it does.

Comment: @JesseWilson changed the answer accordingly.